# How would I access this attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a td attribute that I would like to pull the contents of. I have tried the following jquery but I am getting an undefined alert. Can someone explain why?

```
<script>
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var items = document.querySelectorAll("td:not(:empty)");
        items.forEach(function (elem) {
            elem.addEventListener("click", function () {
                showModal('modal1', 'rotate');
                changeSrc();
            });

        });
    });

function changeSrc(){
        $(".tabs, .tab active, td").on("click", function(){
            var dataId = $(this).attr("data-ticker");
            alert(dataId);
        });
}
</script>

<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tabs-list">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Day 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Day 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><div class="tzh">Time (ET)</div></th>
                    <th>Track I</th>
                    <th>Track II</th>
                    <th>Track III</th>
                    <th>Track IV</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>08:00</th>
                    <td data-ticker="about3" colspan="1" rowspan="2" class="pres">Presentation Title<span>8:00 - 9:00</span><span>Presenter</span></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
```

Yes the rest of the table is cut off to keep it simple.

Comment: Where is the `changeSrc` function being called? You don't show that in your code. Please edit your question so that it accurately represents what your actual code is.

Comment: You've also got a stray `div` inside of a `tr` and a `th` inside of a `tr` that is inside of `tbody`, which is not valid.

Comment: @ScottMarcus the code has been updated to reflect those changes

Comment: I can't see any good reason to add an event listener, inside an event listener, inside an event. Is there a reason you are doing it this way? Your final click listener won't be applied until the item is first clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you only need the nested event handler. But, you are only going to get a value in the `alert` when you click on an element that has a `data-ticker` attribute, so that should probably be the selector you use to find the elements to set the event up on.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tabs-list">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Day 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Day 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><div class="tzh">Time (ET)</div></th>
                    <th>Track I</th>
                    <th>Track II</th>
                    <th>Track III</th>
                    <th>Track IV</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>08:00</td>
                    <td data-ticker="about3" colspan="1" rowspan="2" class="pres">Presentation Title<span>8:00 - 9:00</span><span>Presenter</span></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                </table>

<!-- If you place your script at the end of the body, there's no 
     need to set up a DOMContentLoaded event handler because by 
     the time the parser gets here, all the HTML in the body will
     have been parsed into memory.  -->
<script>
  $("[data-ticker]").on("click", function(event){
     alert(this.dataset.ticker);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: And if the OP wants to keep it "full jquery" : `$(this).data("ticker")` .... personlaly I'd sitck to good 'ol javascript

Comment: This makes sense. The reason I am using it in the beginning is because I could like to use that attribute information to change the src of an iframe I have.